# String length in twips java

Tags: java, html, string

Is there a way to get the string length in [twips](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twip)?
java implementation would be good.

Comment: Can you be more precise concerning your question context ? Are you talking about a Swing application ? A web application rendered in web browser ?

Comment: A string is just a string no? Twips is surely a function of how the string is rendered to the screen? Is this reference to a GUI lib or applets or something? Edit: I've just noticed your HTML tag, so presumably you're talking about the twip length of a string as rendrered in a web page?

Comment: I think it's confusing why the HTML tag is added on this.  Do you want this in Java Swing or in Javascript HTML?  I'm voting to close as "too vague".

Comment: well it i am using java servlet to display the text as html. i need the text width in twips to do line breaks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get the width of a char or String, displayed in a certain font, with `FontMetrics.stringWidth()`. This should be the size in Points. A point is equal to 20 twips.

So this should work:

```
Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 10);
FontMetrics fm = new FontMetrics(font);
int widthInTwips = fm.stringWidth("Hello World") * 20;
```

Comment: And someone manages to provide an excellent answer in the face of extreme vagueness... +1

Comment: @Richard (never heard of "twips" before and was just curious ;-) )