# Finding the length of the string

Tags: java, string

```
String str="This is interesting";
```

How can I find the length of the string ?

**Conditions:**

1) Not to use any String methods

Comment: Count with your fingers?

Comment: Maybe it's me, but I don't see any educational value in such questions

Comment: Write a loop that counts the letters.

Comment: Did you ever read your class book? If you could have see so many examples for this purpose.

Comment: @alexis -- but how do you terminate the loop?

Comment: This is the first time am posting under homework tag. I was asked this question in an interview. Thats why I posted it under homework. I have tried, dint find any solution, so asked here. Upto you all if to answer or close it

Comment: possible duplicate of [String length without using length() method in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910336/string-length-without-using-length-method-in-java). Also read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133701/string-length-in-twips-java)... Its interesting...

Comment: Who knows? It's a contrived program, and it's homework. I'm just giving him something to think about. He could use an iterator, if they've learned them already.

Comment: @MPlatvoet -- Maybe the "educational value" is that some programming problems don't have a good answer -- usually because the wrong question is being asked.

Comment: Thanks Fahim. This link looks helpful

Comment: `Int32 count = 0; String target = "Foo"; foreach (Char item in target) { count++;} //Display count` This isn't java, this is c# code. But basically idea is the same. Use foreach loop.

Comment: And honestly, the interviewer is stupid. If I was asked a such question I'd humilate the asker with a loud laughter.

Comment: Even I wanted to laugh. It was a stupid interview on the whole. They were rather happy asking puzzles than testing the conceptual knowledge

Comment: Ah, interview question, that's different! The C approach: Find out how strings are represented, and read off the length bytes (it's not a C string) via pointer arithmetic. The python approach: Iterate over the string and count the characters. The java approach: Cast it to something whose methods you *are* allowed to use? The google approach: look on the web for more solutions. It's a lousy question in terms of "educational value", but I can see how it could be revealing in a job interview. (I'd have probably answered "What could possibly be the point of that?" :-)

Comment: The questions asked never had anything to do with testing the programming skills. All were silly and gets your confidence degraded. Ended up frustrated the whole day and thought of finding the answers.

Comment: `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(string); return sb.length();`

Answer (score 2):

If you can't use any `String` methods to find the length of the `String`, you can use [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) (Hint: `String#length` returns the field `count`). However, seeing as this is homework, I think you may have misunderstood the question you're being asked.

Comment: I haven't been understanding it differently. I am meant not to use any methods in String. They want us to think differently and find out. Using reflections ?? How?

Comment: @Ajj I linked you to the reflection tutorial. This is homework, so I won't do it for you. You probably want to take a look at the [Member](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/index.html) section of that tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

is `str.length();` still not allowed?

OR [New Link (StringLength.java)](http://pastebin.com/NX7PjUae)

Comment: Bad site.  Invalid security certificate.

Comment: ok due to `bad site` comment, i'll update my answer.